# How to associate A background process with splash screen on codename one

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I am working with Codename One to develop a mobile application. I wish to know how to perform a long duration action, such as loading data from an online server, during a splash screen animation. I understand that this is what splash screens are for. However, I don't know how to associate a background process with a splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just override beforeSplashForm method and call connectionRequest in this mehtod for loading data from server in splash screen and call next form after the connection.